# VScode opens blank browser window when running HTML file using WSL

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I tried both run and run and debug and all it does is open a blank browser window when trying to run an error free simple HTML document through WSL. It runs perfectly fine on my windows machine. This blank tab would be google.com and if im trying to access it using the address on computer root/user etc.. it says file does not exist